# Retrofit 2.2 error URL Android Studio

Tags: android, retrofit2

i'm using Retrofit 2.2 in Android Studio, this is my class ServerTime:

```
public class ServerTime {

@SerializedName("time")
private String time;
@SerializedName("date")
private String date;
@SerializedName("milliseconds_since_epoch")
private String milliSeconds;

public String getTime() {
    return time;
}

public void setTime(String time) {
    this.time = time;
}

public String getDate() {
    return date;
}

public void setDate(String date) {
    this.date = date;
}

public String getMilliSeconds() {
    return milliSeconds;
}

public void setMilliSeconds(String milliSeconds) {
    this.milliSeconds = milliSeconds;
}
}
```

My interface:

```
public interface Api {
@GET("/")
public Call<ServerTime> getServerTime();
}
```

And my method is:

```
void fetchTime2() {
    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("http://luisbaltodano.pe.hu/Galeria/Time.php/")                
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();
    Api api = retrofit.create(Api.class);
    Call<ServerTime> serverTimeCall = api.getServerTime();
    serverTimeCall.enqueue(new Callback<ServerTime>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<ServerTime> call, Response<ServerTime> response) {
            ServerTime serverTime = response.body();
            tvNombre.setText("Date: " + serverTime.getDate());
            tvCelular.setText("Time: " + serverTime.getTime());
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<ServerTime> call, Throwable t) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error while fetching time", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}
```

When I run, only display the Toast in onFailure method.

Now, when I change the BaseUrl for:

```
 .baseUrl("http://date.jsontest.com/")
```

This work perfectly...

Please help me :( .. Check the Url's:

http://luisbaltodano.pe.hu/Galeria/Time.php/

http://date.jsontest.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should change your backend part: http://luisbaltodano.pe.hu/Galeria/Time.php/ should return json content with next header: `Content-Type:application/json;`. Now it returns `text/html`.